# when installing bulma css with angular module is not found

Tags: angular, bulma

I am trying to startup Angular using ng serve command.

And I immediately run into the following issue

> ERROR in multi ./src/styles.scss ../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'C:\client\node_modules\bulma\css\bulma.css' in 'C:\client\ngpop'

I can confirm that the bulma.css exists in the location.

Any ideas

Comment: Can you check the angular.json file? Check if the location of Bulma in styles array is right. In there you can declare like this-  "node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `"node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css"` **angular.json** file style array like below

Angular 6 and above Add like below in **angular.json** file under styles array.

```
    "styles": [

         "node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css",
    ]
```

Angular 2/4/5 you can add like below in **angular-cli.json** file under styles array

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css",
]
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I didn't have this error but bulma styles were just now showing after installation. Your answer solved my issue as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me, the version used was `Angular8`, in `angular.json`:

```
"styles": ["node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.min.css", "src/styles.scss"]
```